# SQL Query not working - No reason?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem. I created a SQL Query, to insert something into the database:

```
INSERT INTO order (kundennummer,empfaenger,adresse,plz,ort,land,email,time,approvalPending) 
VALUES ('232784', 'Niklas Peters', 'Some Stret', 'PostalCode', 'Wien', 'AT', 'email@email.com', '1454593142', '1')
```

But I always get the Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'order
>   (kundennummer,empfaenger,adresse,plz,ort,land,email,time,approvalPending)
>   ' at line 1

My Code is PHP

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO order (kundennummer,empfaenger,adresse,plz,ort,land,email,time,approvalPending) VALUES ('".$kdnr."', '".$emp."', '".$adresse."', '".$plz."', '".$ort."', '".$land."', '".$email."', '".$time."', '1')";
```

I just dont know what is wrong - Am I blind?

Cheers - would be glad for help!

Comment: `order` is a reserved term, need to backtick it. Depending on your assignment of the variables you might be ope to SQL injections with this code as well.

Comment: Hi By manually adding in the database is it working?

Answer (score 13):

Quote order with backticks:

```
INSERT INTO `order` (kundennummer,empfaenger,adresse,plz,ort,land,email,time,approvalPending) 
VALUES ('232784', 'Niklas Peters', 'Some Stret', 'PostalCode', 'Wien', 'AT', 'email@email.com', '1454593142', '1');
```

`ORDER (R)` is [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).

> Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them

Comment: Thanks a Million!!! I Didnt know Order was a reserved Word... You never Stop learning :)

Answer (score 5):

Your table name matches a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), so will need to be quoted in SQL queries, e.g

```
INSERT INTO `order` (kundennummer,empfaenger,adresse,plz,ort,land,email,time,approvalPending) VALUES ('232784', 'Niklas Peters', 'Some Stret', 'PostalCode', 'Wien', 'AT', 'email@email.com', '1454593142', '1')
```

NB. When calling this from PHP, you may want to consider using prepared queries a la PDO, etc.

Comment: "quoted" not equal to `back-ticked`. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JayBlanchard the manual refers to it as "quoted": "Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as described in Section 9.2, “Schema Object Names”: "

Comment: I know that it does, we can just be better than the docs.